# Make ScrollViewer fill dynamic area

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

In the example below I cannot get the ScrollViewer to fill the space available, The height is unknown due to the dynamic content above but is there no way it can fill the space available instead of over running?

```
   <Grid x:Name="Main" Height="200" MaxHeight="200">
      <StackPanel>
         <Grid x:Name="MainContent" Height="170" MaxHeight="170">
            <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Dynamic data "/>
               <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="height "/>
               <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="unknown... "/>
               <Grid x:Name="Results" Background="Red">
                  <ScrollViewer>
                     <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Result set... 0"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Result set... 1"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Result set... 2"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Result set... 3"/>
                     </StackPanel>
                  </ScrollViewer>
               </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
         </Grid>
         <Grid x:Name="Nav">
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Back"/>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Forward"/>
         </Grid>
      </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in `MainContent` `Grid` use `DockPanel` instead of `StackPanel` with `LastChildFill=True`, something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainContent" Height="170" MaxHeight="170">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="24" Text="Dynamic data "/>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="24" Text="height "/>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="24" Text="unknown... "/>
        <Grid x:Name="Results" Background="Red">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Result set... 0"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Result set... 1"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Result set... 2"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Result set... 3"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>               
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

then last element of `DockPanel` will adjust itself to available space

Comment: I wouldn't resort to this. Firstly the "MainContent" Grid by itself seems to serve no specific purpose from the OP's layout and even if it was vitally needed, `RowDefinitions` should be used in that `Grid` than resort to the addition of another LayoutContainer inside it as the sole child to get behavior that the `Grid` could do by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding another element for the Scrollviewer's Height to bind:

```
<grid Grid.row="3" x:Name="Mirror">
</grid>
<ScrollViewer Grid.row="3" Height="{Binding ElementName=uxMirror,XPath=ActualHeight}">
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly your layout is kind of a mess. Why do you need to put a `StackPanel` as the only child of a `Grid`. For the Rows? Use `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` when dealing with `Grid`

From my understanding of your layout, you can pretty much do everything you need with just a `Grid` and a `DockPanel`. When dealing with layout containers, Aim to get your layout with the "least" number of containers as "efficiently" possible. Even if it aint any real performance benefit, it helps enormously when going through someone else's code to not  have redundant nesting

```
<Grid x:Name="Main">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
              FontSize="24"
              Text="Dynamic data " />
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
              FontSize="24"
              Text="height " />
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
              FontSize="24"
              Text="unknown... " />
  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3"
                Background="Red">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock FontSize="24"
                  Text="Result set... 0" />
      <TextBlock FontSize="24"
                  Text="Result set... 1" />
      <TextBlock FontSize="24"
                  Text="Result set... 2" />
      <TextBlock FontSize="24"
                  Text="Result set... 3" />
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
  <DockPanel x:Name="Nav"
              Grid.Row="4"
              LastChildFill="False">
    <Button Content="Back"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    <Button Content="Forward"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
  </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

This should give you everything your looking for. If you need to restrict `Height` dimensions with static values, Add them in accordingly when absolutely needed.

As for the "Nav" `DockPanel`, yes you can using `HorizontalAlignment` get your `Button`'s positioned Left and Right and thereby not use the `DockPanel`, but that would go against the concept of trying to keep "one" item in a `Grid` cell and hence the `DockPanel` usage.

Comment: This is what I've been using but the `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` on the `ScrollViewer` is not working the way it does on other controls in my case either.